# Don't redraw the table in Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I try to make filters for my table, but when I want to draw only filtered data, it nothing do.
I use Datatables. Use ServerSide. When I try to filter, it just nothing does. In console good, but nothing works

```
 function applyFilters() {
                var selectedFilters = {};

                $('.column-filter:checked').each(function () {
                    var columnIndex = $(this).data('column-index');
                    var filterValue = $(this).data('value');
                    if (!selectedFilters[columnIndex]) {
                        selectedFilters[columnIndex] = [];
                    }
                    selectedFilters[columnIndex].push(filterValue);
                });

                for (var columnIndex in selectedFilters) {
                    if (selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(columnIndex)) {
                        var filterValues = selectedFilters[columnIndex];
                        var filterString = filterValues.join('|');
                        console.log(filterValues);
                        console.log(filterString);
                        console.log(table.columns(columnIndex).search(filterString));
                        table.columns(columnIndex).search(filterString);
                    }
                }

                table.draw();
            }
```

```
$filterParams = isset($_POST['filterParams']) ? json_decode($_POST['filterParams'], true) : [];
if (!empty($filterParams)) {
    foreach ($filterParams as $column => $filterValues) {
        if (!empty($filterValues) && in_array($column, $columns)) {
            $filterValues = array_map([$conn, 'real_escape_string'], $filterValues);
            $filterValues = "'" . implode("', '", $filterValues) . "'";
            $sql .= " AND $column IN ($filterValues)";
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work

Comment: I found that table.rows.add(filteredData).draw(); calls a sort.php, but idk why

Comment: I wrote this
                        table.clear().draw();
                        table.rows.add(filteredData);
                        table.columns.adjust().draw();
and sort.php after filter php calls 2 times...

Comment: But if I do search sort.php calls anyway but it works fine. But filter doesn't work